# How to connect a Treeview to a list in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I want to create a table with tkinter.

I was about to use multiple Listboxes adjacent to each other, but I discovered ttk.Treeview.

However, I don't see any alternative to Listboxes' `'-listvariable'` using Treeview.

There will be many modifications, so the `insert` method doesn't seem efficient. This is why I tried to find a way to update values in the table every time a `Stringvar()` is updated ; just like when I write for example :

`variable1 = Stringvar(value=list_of_first_column_values)`

`column1 = Listbox(variable1)`

In the case of a `Treeview()`, this `Stringvar()`'s value would be a list of rows (that would be lists of strings). But I didn't find any way to do this.

Is there a way to connect a Treeview to a variable ?

Comment: as I know `Treeview` doesn't have this function. But what is the problem to write function which gets `list of strings` and it split `string` to `list` and it runs loop to `insert` these values

Comment: There is no problem with it. I just wanted to know if `Treeview`s permitted that already, or if there was another way to make a table which had this function.

Comment: I think you can find all information about `Treeview` on [TkDoc](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/tree.html) and [New Mexico Tech](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-Treeview.html). There is also link to documentation for `tcl/tk` (and `tkinter` is a wrapper on `tcl/tk`) [ttk.treeview](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/ttk_treeview.htm)